# Make externed enum "public" for Python?

Tags: python, cython, extern

I'm wrapping a library that makes massive use of enumerations and therefore contains many constant identifiers. Is there a way to make them available to Cython (declare them as `extern`) and at the same time make them available to Python?

I search for something like this

```
cdef extern from *:
    public enum:
        spam
        foo
        ham
```

which should replace

```
cdef extern from *:
    enum:
        cspam "spam"
        cfoo "foo"
        cham "ham"

spam = cspam
foo = cfoo
ham = cham
```

*Note: I know about the option to move the extern-declarations to a .pxd file to avoid naming-collision.*

Thanks, Niklas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `ctypesgen.py` with some success for exporting types and enumerations.  This would likely be adequate for both python and cython.